# Execute Build Step Based On Parameter Value

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job in which I have defined 2 Execute Shell Build Steps (call them Step1 and Step2. I also have as part of this job a Choice Parameter with 2 choices (for the sake of this example let's also call those values Step1 and Step2). What I am trying to do is if the user selects Step1 as the choice parameter then the job would only execute the Step1 build step, if user selects Step2 it would only select the Step2 build step. I was thinking that I could put a groovy step in front of these to control this behavior but not sure how to construct this. I could also just define a single choice parameter and condition such that if choice = step1 then execute step1 else execute step2......still not sure how to construct that syntax. I'll keep trying a few different things but if anyone has done this any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build):

> The parameter are available as environment <s>parameters</s> variables. So e.g. a shell ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

[Correction by me.]

Use the environment variable defined in your Choice Parameter in two [Conditional BuildSteps](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin), one for each of your steps.